# What float does inside the float?

Tags: css, css-float

If I have container and I floated it to the right, will elements I float inside(eg. left) float to the left until it reaches edge of float container? Or I need to assign position:relative; for float to control it inside container?

Comment: true true ;) I'm loading browser right away, but I just waned to hear some advices from proz, but never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will float wherever you want it to float.
Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/79nRM/:

HTML

```
<div class="placeholder">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="element left"></div>
        <div class="element right"></div>
        <div class="element left"></div>
        <div class="element right"></div>
        <div class="element left"></div>
        <div class="element right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.placeholder {width:400px; height:400px;background-color:#cecece;}
#container {float:right;width:200px;height:400px;background-color: Blue;}
.element {width:50px; height:50px;background-color: Red;clear:both;}

.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
```

Comment: use padding on the container if you need to control the space near the edge

http://jsfiddle.net/79nRM/1/

Answer (score -1):

Well position:relative will not be effected by the float. Position relative means if you use tags such as top: 0px, left: 0px the amount defined in these will be relative to its parent.

While i believe a working html example would help here. An element that has a parent floated right can still, inside its parent be floated left yes.